# Is python with block self closing opened resource?

Tags: python, io

I'm a quite experimented Java developer and I am wondering wether the with block in python is acting the same as a Java embedded `try/catch`. In the following examples, I'm writing to a random file in python and Java

```py
import io

with io.open("filename", "w") as file:
   file.write("a test")
   #is file.close() necessary here ?
   #file.close()
```

```java
File file = new File("test.txt");
try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file)) {
    writer.write("a test");
    // here writer.close() is useless as it is auto closed by the try catch block
} catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

are those 2 block acting exactly the same, or is the python block not closing the resource until program ends ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

([`open` is a builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), so you don't need to import `io`, [`io.open` is simply an alias for `open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html).)

Using your example behaves as if you did:

```
file = open('filename', 'w')
try:
    file.write("a test")
finally:
    file.close()
```

So this means the file is closed automatically, both on success or if an exception is raised.

For more information on the `with` statement, I recommend the Python documentation:

- [The `with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with)
- [With Statement Context Managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers)
- [`contextlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html)

Context managers are really useful and versatile tools, I recommend reading more about them!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in this particular case, `with` is acting similarly to Java's try-with-resource construct. The file is closed when the `with` block is exited.

The purpose of the `with` block is more general though. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) for a description of the use of context managers. The exact behavior of the `with` block depends on the `__enter__`, and more commonly the `__exit__` methods of the object being given to the `with` block. In this case, `open` returns a `TextIOWrapper` object (or a similar class; it can vary), and `TextIOWrapper` defines an `__exit__` method that closes itself when called.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```py
with open('filename', 'w') as file:
    file.write('a test')
```

You do not need to call `file.close`. The file will be closed when the `with` block exits, *even if an exception was raised*. This is part of the advantage of using `with`.